# Memory Error: Numpy.random.normal

Tags: python, numpy, memory, theano

In theano the following code snippet is throwing Memory error:

```
self.w = theano.shared(
        np.asarray(
            np.random.normal(
                loc=0.0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/n_out), size=(n_in, n_out)),
            dtype=theano.config.floatX),
        name='w', borrow=True)
```

Just to mention the size n_in=64*56*56 and n_out=4096. The snippet is taken from the **init** method of a Fully Connected Layer. See the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
File "final.py", line 510, in __init__
loc=0.0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/n_out), size=(n_in, n_out)),
File "mtrand.pyx", line 1636, in mtrand.RandomState.normal    (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:20676)
File "mtrand.pyx", line 242, in mtrand.cont2_array_sc (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:7401)
MemoryError
```

Is there any way we can get around the problem?

Comment: This is a huge array (822 million elements!). It's very unlikely you actually need to allocate that.

Comment: The workaround it is simple: Try it with less elements :)

Comment: @MSeifert  the array is being used to save Deep Neural Networks' parameters, we have to initialize all parameters randomly to get start with the problem. In order to reduce the number of parameters as you are suggesting, we will have to change the network architecture, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MemoryError` is Pythons way of saying: "I tried getting enough memory for that operation but your OS says it doesn't have enough".

So there's no workaround. You have to do it another way (or buy more RAM!). I don't know what your `floatX` is, but your array contains `64*56*56*4096` elements that translates to:

- 6.125 GB if you use `float64`
- 3.063 GB if you use `float32`
- 1.531 GB if you use `float16` (not sure if `float16` is supported for your operations though)

But the problem with `MemoryError`s is that just avoiding them **once** generally isn't enough. If you don't change your approach you'll get problems again as soon as you do an operation that requires an intermediate or new array (then you have two huge arrays) or that coerces to a higher dtype (then you have two huge arrays and the new one is of higher dtype so requires more space).

So the only viable workaround is to change the approach, maybe you can start by calculating subsets (map-reduce approach)?